# SQL query, one to many, with count number of each match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pivot

I'm coding a custom query on wordpress (php), with a custom database in SQL.

I have two tables:

```
| table.carMake  |    | table.carmodels                 |
|----------------|    |---------------------------------|
| id | make      |    | ID | makeId| modelname| price   |    
|----|-----------|    |----|-------|----------|---------|
| 1  | toyota    |    | 1  | 1     | A        | low     |
| 2  | mazda     |    | 2  | 3     | B        | med     |
| 3  | tesla     |    | 3  | 3     | C        | high    |
                      | 4  | 2     | D        | med     |
                      | 5  | 2     | E        | med     |
                      | 6  | 2     | F        | low     |
```

I want to make a query that will return an array like this:

```
$modelprices = 
[
   make: toyota,
   low: 1,
   medium: 0,
   high: 0,
],
[
   make: mazda,
   low: 1,
   medium: 2,
   high: 0,
],
[
   make: tesla,
   low: 0,
   medium: 1,
   high: 1,
]
```

I've been hunting around but my SQL knowledge is fairly limited. Thank you!

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you, I have prepared SQL Query with DB Fiddle. Here I have used CASE when with sum for make and price wise qty.

```
SELECT CM.make,
SUM(CASE CMS.price WHEN 'LOW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LOW,
SUM(CASE CMS.price WHEN 'HIGH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIGH,
SUM(CASE CMS.price WHEN 'MED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MED
FROM
carMake AS CM 
INNER JOIN carmodels AS CMS ON CMS.makeId = CM.id
GROUP BY CM.make;
```

DB Fiddle Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dfb7344abd06a6a7130e1f4eef293476.
This include creation of table and query.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly :) Amazing. Still don't understand how haha

Answer (score 0):

this sql query should return the 3 columns:

1. make name (for example: toyota)
2. price (for example: low)
3. a "count" of the combination, *if exists* (for example: the number of low priced toyotas, which is 1 in this case)

```
from table.carMake cmk join table.carmodels cmd on (cmk.id = cmd.makeId)
group by cmk.make, cmd.price;
```

I haven't tested it so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll correct it.

good luck!:)

Comment: Before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Don't put code on the code block delimiter line; text on that line won't show up; you can put a language there. Find out about running code online. Code questions should have a [mre] that answerers can cut & paste & run, so when you have enough rep to comment, tell askers to give one when one is missing. But anyway please don't answer duplicate questions, vote to close them.

Comment: Repeating code in natural language is seldom enlightening, we can see the code. Explain why certain code was chosen. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean. PS Please use standard punctuation & spelling. Please leave social communications like greetings, thanks, etc out of posts. [answer] [help]

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

select 'make: ' + c.make,

case when cm.price = 'low'

then 'low: ' + count(cm.price) else 'low: ' + '0' end,

case when cm.price = 'medium'

then 'medium: ' + count(cm.price)

else 'medium: ' + '0' end,

case when cm.price = 'high'

then 'high: ' + count(cm.price)

else 'high: ' + '0' end

from table.carMake c

inner join table.carmodels cms on cm.id = cms.makeid

Comment: Before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Code-only answers are generally poor, explain how it answers the question. [answer] [help]